# KEDAScalerFailed : no azure identity found for request clientID

Tags: azure, keda

I tried various different methods but not able to access the Azure Storage Queues via PodIdentity. The resource group, client ID already exists.
The steps:-

1. kubectl create namespace keda
2. helm install keda kedacore/keda --set podIdentity.activeDirectory.identity= --namespace keda
3. kubectl create namespace myapp
4. The first few sections of myapp.yaml :

```
apiVersion: aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1
kind: AzureIdentity
metadata:
  name: <idvalue>
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  clientID: "<clientId>"
  resourceID: "<resourceId>"
  type: 0
---
apiVersion: aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1
kind: AzureIdentityBinding
metadata:
  name: <idvalue>-binding
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  azureIdentity: <idvalue>
  selector: <idvalue> #keeping same as identity
---
```

The rest of the file is the deployment section, so not pasting here.

Then ran the Helm to deploy the myapp.yaml via myappInt.values.yaml file ->
helm install  -f C:\MyApp\myappInt.values.yaml (this file contains the clustername, role etc.)

myappInt.values.yaml file:-

```
image:
  registry: <registryname>

deployment:
  environment: INT
  clusterName: <clustername>
  clusterRole: <clusterrole>
  region: <region>
  processingRegion: <processingregion>
  azureIdentityClientId: "<clientId>"
  azureIdentityResourceId: "<resourceId>"
```

5. Then the scaler ->
   kubectl apply -f c:\MyApp\kedascaling.yaml --namespace myapp

The kedascaling.yaml:-

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: keda-pod-identity-auth  
spec:
  podIdentity:
    provider: azure
---
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: myapp-scaledobject
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: myapp # Corresponds with Deployment Name
  minReplicaCount: 2
  maxReplicaCount: 3
  triggers:
  - type: azure-queue
    metadata:      
      queueName: myappqueue # Required      
      accountName: myappstorage # Required when pod identity is used      
      queueLength: "1" # Required          
    authenticationRef:
      name: keda-pod-identity-auth # AuthenticationRef would need pod identity
```

**Finally it gives the error below:-**

```
kind: Event
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myapp-scaledobject.16def024b939fdf2
  namespace: myappnamespace
  uid: someuid
  resourceVersion: '186302648'
  creationTimestamp: '2022-03-23T06:55:54Z'
  managedFields:
    - manager: keda
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: v1
      time: '2022-03-23T06:55:54Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:count: {}
        f:firstTimestamp: {}
        f:involvedObject:
          f:apiVersion: {}
          f:kind: {}
          f:name: {}
          f:namespace: {}
          f:resourceVersion: {}
          f:uid: {}
        f:lastTimestamp: {}
        f:message: {}
        f:reason: {}
        f:source:
          f:component: {}
        f:type: {}
involvedObject:
  kind: ScaledObject
  namespace: myapp
  name: myapp-scaledobject
  uid: <some id>
  apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
  resourceVersion: '<some version>'
**reason: KEDAScalerFailed
message: |
  no azure identity found for request clientID** 
source:
  component: keda-operator
firstTimestamp: '2022-03-23T06:55:54Z'
lastTimestamp: '2022-03-23T07:30:54Z'
count: 71
type: Warning
eventTime: null
reportingComponent: ''
reportingInstance: ''
```

**Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Asked at Keda repo but no response.**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error recently... I needed to make sure that the AAD Pod Identity was in the same namespace as the KEDA operator service.

Whatever identity you assigned to KEDA when creating KEDA with HELM, ensure that it's within the same namespace (which in your instance is "keda").

For example after running:

```
helm install keda kedacore/keda --set podIdentity.activeDirectory.identity=my-keda-identity --namespace keda
```

if **my-keda-identity** is not in namespace "keda" then the KEDA operator will not be able to bind AAD because it can't find it. If you need to update the AAD reference you can simply run:

```
helm upgrade keda kedacore/keda --set podIdentity.activeDirectory.identity=my-second-app-reference --namespace keda
```

Next, recreate the KEDA operator pod (I like to do this to test things out in a clean manor) and then run the following command to see if binding worked:

```
kubectl logs -n keda <keda-operator-pod-name> -c keda-operator
```

You should see the error go away (as long as the identity has access to retrieve queue messages from Azure Storage via RBAC)